# Adjust margin for forestplot, footnotes

Tags: r, graphics, r-forestplot

I'm trying to use the forestplot and I want to include a lengthy footnote (3 lines of text). I can't get enough space at the bottom and I don't think the `par()` options are doing anything. Here's the example given in the vingette along with my attempt at making a footnote[image]:

```
library(forestplot)
# Cochrane data from the 'rmeta'-package
cochrane_from_rmeta <- 
  structure(list(
    mean  = c(NA, NA, 0.578, 0.165, 0.246, 0.700, 0.348, 0.139, 1.017, NA, 0.531), 
    lower = c(NA, NA, 0.372, 0.018, 0.072, 0.333, 0.083, 0.016, 0.365, NA, 0.386),
    upper = c(NA, NA, 0.898, 1.517, 0.833, 1.474, 1.455, 1.209, 2.831, NA, 0.731)),
    .Names = c("mean", "lower", "upper"), 
    row.names = c(NA, -11L), 
    class = "data.frame")

tabletext<-cbind(
  c("", "Study", "Auckland", "Block", 
    "Doran", "Gamsu", "Morrison", "Papageorgiou", 
    "Tauesch", NA, "Summary"),
  c("Deaths", "(steroid)", "36", "1", 
    "4", "14", "3", "1", 
    "8", NA, NA),
  c("Deaths", "(placebo)", "60", "5", 
    "11", "20", "7", "7", 
    "10", NA, NA),
  c("", "OR", "0.58", "0.16", 
    "0.25", "0.70", "0.35", "0.14", 
    "1.02", NA, "0.53"))
dev.new()
par(mar = c(4, 1, 1, 1))
forestplot(tabletext, 
           cochrane_from_rmeta,new_page = TRUE,
           is.summary=c(TRUE,TRUE,rep(FALSE,8),TRUE),
           clip=c(0.1,2.5), 
           xlog=TRUE, 
           col=fpColors(box="royalblue",line="darkblue", summary="royalblue"))
grid.text('* Adjusted for demographic & baseline variables,blur blur blur',
          x = unit(.43, 'npc'),
          y = unit(1, 'lines'))
```

Any suggestions on how to create some more space?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I find a solution, first I though that I could change the margine thanks to the ggplot option of the theme :

```
+ theme(plot.margin = margin(2, 2, 2, 2, "cm"))
```

But it was not possible to have access to the plot object in `forestplot`, so I look closly the option of `forestplot` function and there is an argument `mar` which take units as parameter, the following solution works for me :

```
forestplot(tabletext, 
           cochrane_from_rmeta,new_page = TRUE,
           is.summary=c(TRUE, TRUE, rep(FALSE,8), TRUE),
           clip=c(0.1, 2.5), 
           xlog=TRUE, 
           mar = unit(rep(10, times = 4), "mm"),
           col=fpColors(box="royalblue",
                        line="darkblue",
                        summary="royalblue"))

grid.text('* Adjusted for demographic & baseline variables,blur blur blur',
          x = unit(.43, 'npc'),
          y = unit(1, 'lines'))
```

Comment: Thanks Remi! I didn't notice the mar option.